# How do you get the cookie of a website after an HTTPS NTLM authentification?

Tags: http, wget, ntlm

I am trying to store a cookie (which will help me authentificate myself elsewhere) given by a website after an authentification.

The case is as follow:

- Get to the HTTPS page
- Get redirected by httpd to an [NTLM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NT_LAN_Manager) authentication page
- Authentify myself
- Get redirected to the first asked page with the authentification cookie

The process works on Mozilla, but I need to do an test script of it. I am using [Wget](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget) or [cURL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL).

I have the following command:

```
wget --cookies="on" --keep-session-cookies --save-cookies="cookies.txt" --load-cookies="cookies.txt" --no-check-certificate --user="user" --password="password" https://example.con/
```

But it does not work. The cookie does not get the authentification credentials and so the last redirection gives me a 401 unauthorized answer.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future reference:

```
curl -v --ntlm --insecure --location-trusted --user 'a':'b' -b cookie.txt https://example.con/ >success.txt 2>&1
```

Then a simple cURL call with the cookie works.